# Building responsive layouts with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

For the past few months, I have been trying to learn iOS development. Most of it has relatively easy, however, one thing has been very difficult for me. *AutoLayout*. After I grasped constraints, I thought it would be easy, but I am having real trouble getting my layouts to look well on both iPhone and iPad devices. I can design pretty well for iOS. Recently, I was building an app where I put two buttons in the ViewController. on iPhone, I set the constraints of the  buttons to equal the width of the screen (plus the screen margin), and set a reasonable looking height to the buttons. On iPhones, my layout looks great, but on iPads (especially the newest iPad Pro), things look horrific. Full width buttons look great on the iPhone, but on iPad they need to be a lot smaller width wise and a lot bigger height wise. Likewise, my images look great on iPhone, but are too small on iPads. In CSS, I could just use MediaQueries, and on Android, resource qualifiers on the values and layouts.

What are my choices here? How can I design my layouts to look nice on both iPhone and iPad when certain dimensions need to be different based on screen size, screen resolution, etc.? Constraints seem to be good for enforcing dimensions, but not adapting them.(Except maybe the Aspect Ratio constraint)

What features of the AutoLayout system can allow me to accomplish responsive layouts among larger screens and Retina resolutions? What are some common tips / tricks for developing responsive layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH6-SW1) in order to build for different screen sizes easily. [raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started) has a solid guide on adaptive layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use size classes to design differently for iPhones and iPads and also you can use proportional width height to look perfect based on the height ratio of all devices. If you want to choose first option then you can go with any tutorial available but if you want to choose the second option which is the little difficult way but time saving way then you need to really understand the sizes of devices and need to understand what actually proportional width and height constraints do. Thanks.